# ExecuteReader Date data type in SQL showing issue

Tags: c#, sql, date, types, executereader

Hello guys I have this code, I have issue when I execute:

`zodjdate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(24);`

or

`zpridate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(23);`

It only shows `date` in that `textBox`. I would like to know if there is any way it can show the full date which is saved in SQL DB?

this is the full code

```
        SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+nc_zajezd_vyber, spojeni); 
        spojeni.Open();
        SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

        if (precti.Read())
        {

            zodjdate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(24);
            zpridate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(23);

        }
        spojeni.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using GetDataTypeName for the dates, so it is showing the correct info. What you want is GetDateTime. More specifically, change the following two lines:

```
        zodjdate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(24);
        zpridate.Text = precti.GetDataTypeName(23);
```

to

```
        zodjdate.Text = precti.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString();
        zpridate.Text = precti.GetDateTime(23).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: zodjdate.Text = precti.GetDateTime(24); If I use this code it has red underlines and gives error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string', Don't you know what it could cause?

Comment: 'zajezd' if I'm right translates as 'race' so I think he needs full datetime or maybe even just time